# Show only relevant search results

Tags: php, html

I have created a page for search, and I'm having some problems.

The data is displayed on the page but I also use some fields on the form for a specific field, so when I enter the data in those fields and hit search, it shows the search field on the top of the display page with the rest of the data, but I want only the data which belongs to my search.

**CODE:**

```html
<?php
   include('connect.php');
?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<?php include('include/head.php')?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                 <?php include('include/menu.php') ?>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div id="logo">
    <?php include('include/logo.php'); ?>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page">

        <div id="page-bgtop">


            <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
                    <div class="entry-image">
                    <?php
                    $q=mysql_query("SELECT count( php ) AS ph, count( dotnet ) AS dot, count( design ) AS des FROM candidate");
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                    {
                    ?>
                    <form name="" method="post">
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="280" height="200">
                    <th colspan="5" bgcolor="orange" >Total Number of Resume by skills</th>
                    <tr>

                    <th><B>PHP</B></th>
                    <th><B>DOTNET</B></th>
                    <th><B>DESIGN</B></th>
                    </tr>

                    <td><?php echo "$row[ph]"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo "$row[dot]"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo  "$row[des]"; ?></td>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>

                    <h2 class="title">Welcome to Resume </h2>



                    <div class="entry">
                        <p>
                        <form name="search" method="post" action="searchview.php">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        Id: <input type="text" name="id"  /></br></br>
                        Name:<input type="text" name="name"  /><br/></br>
                        Expected Salary:<input type="text" name="es" /><br/></br>
                        Skill Rate: <input type="text" name="sr" /><br/>   </br>
                        Salary:<input type="text" name="cs" /></br></br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="seach" /><input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" />
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        </form>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post" >
                <?php
                $query=mysql_query("select * from candidate");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                $sno=$row['id'];
                $image=$row['image'];
                $name=$row['fname'];
                $es=$row['es'];
                $sr=$row['sr'];
                $cs=$row['cs'];
                ?>
                <form name="view" method="post" action="searchview.php" >
                <table border="1" cellpadding="30" class="centered" width="20" >
                <tr>
                <th width="150">S.NO</th>
                <th width="150">IMAGE</th>
                <th width="150">NAME</th>
                <th width="150">EXPECTED SALARY</th>
                <th width="150">SKILL RATE</th>
                <th width="150">SALARY</th>
                <th width="150">ACTION</th>
                </tr>

                <td><?php echo "$row[id]"; ?></td>
                <td><div class="rightdiv1a"><img src="<?php echo 'img/'.$row['image']; ?>" style="height:120px; width:145px; "></div></td>
                <td><?php echo "$row[fname]"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$row[es]"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$row[sr]"; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$row[cs]"; ?></td>
                <td><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>"><img alt='view' title='view' src='images/view.png' width='15px' height='15px' hspace='20' /></a></td>
                <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>"><img alt='Edit' title='Edit' src='images/edit.png' width='15px' height='15px' hspace='20' /></a></td>
                <td><a onclick="return confirm('Would you like to delete?');" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo "$row[id]"; ?>"><img alt='delete' title='delete' src='images/delete.png' width='15px' height='15px' hspace='20' /></a></td>
                </table>
                </form> 
                <?php
                }?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer-bgcontent">
    <div id="footer">
          <?php//   include('include/footer.php');?>    
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php// } ?>
```

This code displays the data now but I want to filter the data and only show the results which belongs to my search, and have the rest disappear.

Here are some screenshots of my form:

[image: search field of the fomr]

[image: And in this table my filter data must displayed here n rest of the data must disappear]

pls help,
thanks in advance..

Comment: hi thanks for the answer,what i really want is,want to show the search form after the search process for another search but in the result table i only want filter result of my search for example when user visit at search page it shows entire data in table form,and also have some search fields,so when user fill a search field n hit search button on that time,i want only the field related answer in the table and the old data must remove from there,forex if i enter a name in field steve so the system must bring search results on behalf of that field only.. must check the screen shots

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to display the search results, but no longer show the search form. If this is the case, then move your second "post" div to the top and wrap it in an if:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
     // Process POST results here:
     ...
     die(); // end processing so the form doesn't display again
}
```